# Colorbox grouping content linked from same page - how to stop it?

Tags: nodes, ajax, media, javascript

I have a page with two links on it that each open in Colorbox modals.

When I click on one of them, it opens them both, as if they were a gallery, with forward and back arrows to navigate between them.

I have looked through the Colorbox configuration options and I can't figure out how to stop this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out, with crucial help from the [#Drupal](http://drupal.org/irc) IRC channel.

I was using [Colorbox Node](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) along with Colorbox, and I was confusing the documentation from the two of them. Specifically, Colorbox requires links to have the class `colorbox-load` while Colorbox Node requires that they have the class `colorbox-node`. The really confusing thing about this is that if you use `colorbox-load` instead of `colorbox-node`, it works, sort of. It was loading the *entire* page including headers, footers, and all markup and styles, into the modal, as if it were an iframe.

So step one was to start using the correct link class.

After changing the link class to `colorbox-node`, however, all I saw in the modal was the title of the target page, unstyled, on a white background. Poking around in the Colorbox settings was, unsurprisingly, unhelpful. Again, #Drupal pointed me in the right direction: Colorbox Node creates a display of the content type and makes the body hidden by default for some reason.

So step two was going to structure > content > [content type of target node] > manage display and choosing "Colorbox" (next to "Default" and "Teaser") to unhide the body of the target node.

Voilá, you now have the title and body pulled out from your target node and appearing isolated in your Colorbox modal.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are using colorbox but if you have image fields in a content type there are setting under "manage display" after you change the field format to colorbox (save it and go back) and look for Gallery (image grouping)